# I am having problem with displaying the svg rectangles

Tags: javascript, firebase, d3.js, svg

My firestore databse is saved in a follwing way: 
*Collection is "test"
*Document "google auto generated id"
*Data: 2 arrays, [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zJd5.png) is month_name = [Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May]
                 [2] is ac_output = [20, 15, 5, 14, 3]

I was able to retrieve data from the database, but none of the rectangles displayed on the browser.  Then, I tried to show one rectangle at a time, but still no success.  I am not even getting any error on the console, so I dont know where the problem is in my code.  I really need help with this. Thanks

```js
//Javascript Code:

//select the svg container
const svg = d3.select('.canvas')
  .append('svg')
    .attr('width', 600)
    .attr('height', 600);

//get data from the firestore
db.collection('test').get().then(res => {

  var data = [];
  res.docs.forEach(doc => {
        data.push(doc.data());
  });

//append data to the rects in the DOM
const rects = svg.selectAll('rect')
                .data(data);

//set the attributes for rects in DOM
  rects.attr('width', 50)
                .attr('height', function(...d) {
                                  return d[0].ac_output})
                .attr('fill', 'orange')
             .attr('x', (d, i) => i*70)

//append the enter selection to the DOM  
   rects.enter()
                .append('rect')
                  .attr('width',50)
                  .attr("height", function(...d) {
                               return(d[0].ac_output})                    
                  .attr('fill', 'orange')
})
```

The expected result is supposed to be a bunch of rectangles on the browser for now, which will eventually be turned into a bar graph.

if I do console.log(data), this image is the output:

[image: console.log(data) output]

Comment: Your update pattern is incorrect and the rest parameters are useless. But you should see the rectangles at the upper left (0,0) corner of the SVG. So, the first step now is doing a `console.log(data)` after the `forEach` and show us the resulting array.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zJd5.png

This is what I get if I log the data to console.

Comment: Thanks, but next time please post **text**, not an image of a text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your data structure, which is effectively this...

```
const data = [{
    ac_output: [10, 15, 20, 15, 5, 9],
    month_name: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun"]
}];
```

...the problem is that you're passing an array with just **one** element to the `data()` method. It seems to me that you want to pass the values in `ac_outcome`. In that case, your data binding should be:

```
const rects = svg.selectAll('rect')
    .data(data[0].ac_output);
```

Besides that, you have two additional problems:

1. Your enter and update selection are wrong. If the only value you plant to change in the subsequent calls is the rect's height, that's the only attribute you should keep in the update selection. Move everything else to the enter selection.
2. You're using the rest parameter incorrectly here. Firstly because the data binding, which we already covered. Second, because this...

   ```
   .attr("height", function(...d) {
   })
   ```

   ...will pass as the parameters an **array** with:

   **a**. the datum;
   **b**. the index;
   **c**. the current group;

   Therefore, for using the datum, you should do:

   ```
   .attr("height", function(...d) {
       //use d[0] here
   })
   ```

   But this is useless, because you can simply do:

   ```
   .attr("height", function(d) {
       //use d here
   })
   ```

Here is your code with those changes:

```js
const svg = d3.select("svg");
const data = [{
  ac_output: [10, 15, 20, 15, 5, 9],
  month_name: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun"]
}];

const rects = svg.selectAll('rect')
  .data(data[0].ac_output);

rects.attr('height', function(d) {
  return d;
});

rects.enter()
  .append('rect')
  .attr('width', 50)
  .attr('x', (d, i) => i * 60)
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return d
  })
  .attr('fill', 'orange')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, just quick question how would I change the x-axis  data values to my month_name array? since the only data I appended with the rects is ac_output .

Comment: You should combine those two arrays in an array of objects.